# score turn based multiplayer android

Tags: java, android

I'm making a little quizz multiplayer game with Google Play Games Services on Turn Based Multiplayer one turn and I have a little trouble since 2 days?

I just use the sample and I stock scores (player 1 and player 2) with the persist method. My problem is when the game is finished, i want to display a layout with scores on de twice devices (player 1 et player 2). My problem is that the first player can't get the score of the second player. In the second player device, there are no troubles.

Here my persist method :

```
public byte[] persist() {
    JSONObject retVal = new JSONObject();

    try {
        retVal.put("player1", namePlayer1);
        retVal.put("player2", namePlayer2);
        retVal.put("scoreP1", scorePlayer1);
        retVal.put("scoreP2", scorePlayer2);
        retVal.put("data", data);
        retVal.put("turnCounter", turnCounter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String st = retVal.toString();

    Log.d(TAG, "==== PERSISTING\n" + st);

    return st.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

and now how I stock scores in the byte array :

```
public void onDoneClicked(View view) {
    showSpinner();
    nextParticipantId = getNextParticipantId();

    // Create the next turn
    mTurnData.turnCounter += 1;
    if(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName().equals(mMatch.getParticipant("p_1").getDisplayName()))
        mTurnData.scorePlayer1 = playerScore;
    else
        mTurnData.scorePlayer2 = playerScore;
```

I display the score in a end_game_layout and TextViews so on the second device all is alrigth but in the first the score of the second player is in null :'(

Thanks for read me and maybe help.